# Indefinite integration $f(x) = \int e^{x^4}{(1+x^2+2x^4)}\,d(e^{x^2}) $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$
> f(x)=\int e^{x^4}{(1+x^2+2x^4)}\,d(e^{x^2})
> $$
> Find $f(1)+f’(0)$, if $f(0) = 0$.

I tried assuming $e^{x^2}$ as a dummy variable $u$, converting everything else in terms of natural log:
$$
f(x) = \int (\ln(u))^2 \bigl[1 + \ln(u) + 2(\ln(u))^2\bigr]\,du
$$

But can't go forward from this

**Edit**
Later understood that $e^{x^4} \neq (e^{x^2})^2$

Comment: $e^{x^{4}}\neq (e^{x^{2}})^{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$
 I=\int e^{x^4}\left(1+x^2+2 x^4\right) d\left(e^{x^2}\right) 
=  \int e^{x^4}\left(1+x^2+2 x^4\right) e^{x^2} d\left(x^2\right)
$$
Letting $y=x^2$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int e^{y^2+y}\left(1+y+2 y^2\right) d y \\
& =\int e^{y^2+y}[y(2 y+1)+1] d y \\
& =\int y d\left(e^{y^2+y}\right)+\int e^{y^2+y} d y \\
& =y e^{y^2+y}-\int e^{y^2+y} d y+\int e^{y^2+y} d y \\
& =y e^{y^2+y}+C\\
& =x^2 e^{x^4+x^2}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I did not understand how we can rewrite the integral, changing the differential operator to $d(x^2)$. How did you get that?

Comment: By the Chain Rule, we have $\frac{d}{d x} v(u(x))=\frac{d v}{d u} \cdot \frac{d u}{d x}.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Suppose $f(x)=p(x)\cdot e^{x^2+x^4}$ (so $p(0)=0$) for some polynomial function $p(x)$, so that upon differentiation we have

$$f'(x) = \left[p'(x) + p(x) (2x+4x^3) \right] e^{x^2+x^4}= 2x (1+x^2+2x^4) e^{x^2+x^4}$$

Finding $p(x)$, if it exists, is now a matter of solving the linear ODE

$$p'(x) + 2x(1+2x^2) p(x) = 2x(1+x^2+2x^4)$$

Answer (score 2):

Given a function $g(x)$ that is $C^\infty$ (smooth) over $\mathbb R$, then a Riemann–Stieltjes integral is equivalent to the Riemann integral of
$$\int_a^b f(x) \text{ d}g(x) = \int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\text{ d}x$$

Your integral $$\int e^{x^4}{(1+x^2+2x^4)}\,d(e^{x^2})$$ has $g(x) = e^{x^2}$, which is smooth, so we can transform your integral into
\begin{align}
\int e^{x^4}{(1+x^2+2x^4)}\cdot 2xe^{x^2}\text{ d}x & = \int e^{x^2(x^2+1)} (2x^4 + x^2 + 1) \cdot 2x \text{ d}x\\
&= \int e^{u(u+1)}(2u^2 + u + 1) \text{ d}u, \qquad u=x^2
\end{align}

Expand out the integrand and integrate the third term by parts, which cancels out the second, leaving the first one. Hence, the antiderivative is $x^2 e^{x^4 + x^2} + C$. If $f(0) = 0$, then $C=0$.

We now have $f(x) = x^2 e^{x^4 + x^2}$, and evaluating $f(1)+f’(0)$ should be trivial.